# multiprocessing's Queue inside Manger.Namespace()

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pathos

I am currently creating a class which is supposed to execute some methods in a multi-threaded way, using the `multiprocessing` module. I execute the real computation using a `Pool` of `n` workers. Now I wanted to assign each of the currently `n` active workers an index between `0` and `n` for some other calculation. To do this, I wanted to use a shared `Queue` to assign an index in a way, that at every time no two workers have the same id. To share the same `Queue` inside the class between the different threads, I wanted to store it inside a `Manager.Namespace()`. But doing this, I got some problems with the `Queue`. Therefore, I created a minimal version of my problem and ended up with something like this:

```
from multiprocess import Process, Queue, Manager, Pool, cpu_count

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        manager = Manager()
        self.ns = manager.Namespace()
        self.ns.q = manager.Queue()

    def foo(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            self.ns.q.put(i)
            print(self.ns.q.get())
            print(self.ns.q.qsize())

a = A()
a.foo()
```

In this code, the execution stops before the second print statement - therefore, I think, that no data is actually written in the `Queue`. When I remove the `namespace` related stuff the code works flawlessly. Is this the intended behaviour of the `multiprocessing`s objects and am I doing something wrong? Or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you should not use `Namespace` here. when you put a `Queue` object into `manager.Namespace()`, each process will get a new `Queue` instance, all the writer/reader of those newly created queue objects have no connection with parent process, therefore no message will be received by worker processes. share a `Queue` solely instead.

by the way, you mentioned "thread" many times, but in the context of `multiprocess` module, a worker is a process, not a thread.